# amavis cronjob throwing an error out of nowhere

Tags: email, postfix, cron, spamassassin, amavis

Can someone explain why amavis cronjob is suddenly trowing the following error?

```
Cron <amavis@bee> test -e /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob && /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob sa-sync

rules: failed to run T_SPF_HELO_PERMERROR test, skipping:
    (Can't locate object method "check_for_spf_helo_permerror" via package "Mail::SpamAssassin::PerMsgStatus" at (eval 1156) line 19.
)
rules: failed to run T_SPF_TEMPERROR test, skipping:
    (Can't locate object method "check_for_spf_temperror" via package "Mail::SpamAssassin::PerMsgStatus" at (eval 1156) line 614.
)
rules: failed to run T_SPF_PERMERROR test, skipping:
    (Can't locate object method "check_for_spf_permerror" via package "Mail::SpamAssassin::PerMsgStatus" at (eval 1156) line 784.
)
rules: failed to run T_SPF_HELO_TEMPERROR test, skipping:
    (Can't locate object method "check_for_spf_helo_temperror" via package "Mail::SpamAssassin::PerMsgStatus" at (eval 1156) line 1129.
)
```

I am not even sure what that cronjob does, but is worked for 2 weeks now without a problem. No configuration changes have been made in this time.

The server was set up fresh, and worked fine (and still does work fine btw.) ;)

Comment: This cronjob do maintenance job for spamassassin. Command `amavisd-new-cronjob sa-sync` [was wrapper](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1945262&p=12302074#post12302074) for command `sa-learn --sync`. Apparently this command will do [synchronization between the database and the journal if needed](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.2.x/doc/sa-learn.html).

Comment: The error started happening this morning. A search on google show this has happened to a lot of people within the last 8-10 hours so i guess we have to wait for a fix...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that some checks that weren't supposed to be released into all update streams have been.  See eg https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183763/spamassassin-object-method-location-problems-after-restart for more details, but that the upshot is that the errors should go away following the next update after the errant rule(s) have been pulled.

**Edit**: yes, this has been confirmed by one of the developers.  From (eg) http://www.mail-archive.com/users@spamassassin.apache.org/msg91187.html , dated 2015-02-09:

> It was part of a commit on Jan 30,
>   http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/spamassassin/commits/190790,
>   that likely needs a has_ function for a can() if encapsulation if you
>   aren't using the latest trunk to avoid warnings.
>
> Working on a patch now and a fix to the rules.

**2nd edit**: according to [this email](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@spamassassin.apache.org/msg91225.html), the problem is now fixed:

> Rule gen just finished and the update does include the fix if you want
>   to confirm.
>
> Regards, KAM

I've just done an `sa-update -D && service spamassassin restart`, and the error's gone for me (running SA 3.3.1 on C6).